# Laravel-Passport always put 1 year in expiration date

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've tried to set the token expiration to 8 hours, but it's always set for 1 year.
In AuthServiceProvider:

```
$time = new \DateTime();
$time->add(new \DateInterval('P0Y0M0DT8H0M'));
Passport::tokensExpireIn($time);
```

This is executed when I log in into the application. Then, Laravel starts to build the app and end executing the build function ( `Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build`). When this code is executed:

```
if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
    return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
}
```

the PassportServiceProvider->registerAuthorizationServer is called and inside the `Passport::tokensExpireIn()` is executed at least 5 times, so since it's called without DateTime parameter it sets the tokens expire time to 1 year again.

I've validated that the first time it enters the tokensExpireIn function it set's the expiration time correctly, but then it execute the previous code and overrides it by 1 year.

Is there any issue with this or is there any way to set the expiration time after this `registerAuthorizationServer()` function?

Comment: which grant you are using ?

Comment: @Wellwisher idk exactly what grant I'm using.. It's the first time using passport and I can't figure out what's exactly what you asked. Could you give me an example? Sorry.

Comment: get the reference from Laravel documentation. check this link https://laravel-news.com/passport-grant-types

Comment: If you are generating `personal access token` then you can't set the expiration.